# Enabling FileStream in existing clustered servers in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering, high-availability, failover

I have heard that enabling FileStream in an already existing clustered environment is tough. I'm working on a consolidation project and currently analyzing the impact it will have if we migrated DBs into an existing server. FileStream is one of the factors and I wanted to get some more info or key elements to know on why it would be hard to enable FileStream in an existing clustered environment that has no FileStream enabled. I'm currently new at this and would truly appreciate any answers!